# AHK if/else of output from Custom Message Box Function

Tags: autohotkey, conditional-statements

I've been trying to create a script that displays message boxes conditioned on the output from another customized message box with more than 3 options.

The custom functions are taken form this thread http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/29570-function-custom-msgbox-custom-buttons/page-2

I've tried both the CMsgbox and the MsgBoxV2 functions, running into the same problem. The Message "IT WORKED!" testing with if(condition) will always appear regardless of whether pressing any of the Sym|&Go|&C options, and the message "worked" will never appear regardless of actually pressing C, In other words no specificity or sensitivity regarding variable testing.

```
!o::
var := MsgBoxV2("Question11","Hi, what's up??","Sym|Go|C","24")
Msgbox 4,, You Pressed %var%

if (%var% = C) 
{  
    Msgbox 4,, IT WORKED!
}

IfEqual, %var%,C
{  
  Msgbox 4,, worked
}
return

!e:: 
var := CMsgbox( "s", "d", "*&Sym|&Go|&C","",1 )
Msgbox 4,, You Pressed %var%
if (%var% = C) 
{  
    Msgbox 4,, IT WORKED!
}

IfEqual, %var%,C
{  
  Msgbox 4,, worked
}
return
```

I don't know if this is because I've misunderstood the if/Else testing in ahk, or if the output from these custom functions cannot be tested, or both. One solution would be to figure out what type of variable %var% is, but I've not been able to find a way to figure that out either.

Thanks for reading and hope you guys can help.

here are the custom message functions for testing.

```
MsgBoxV2(Title="",Text="",Buttons="",IconPath="",Timeout="",Font="",Schriftart="Arial",Colors="||",WindowStyles="",GuiNr = "")
{
Static Stat2,Stat1
Col1:="0xFFFFFF" ,Col2:="0x000000",Col3:="0x000000", Color1:="", Color2:="", Color3:=""
Loop, Parse, Colors,`|
Color%A_Index% := (A_Loopfield = "") ? Col%A_Index% : A_Loopfield
Loop 3
Color%A_Index% := (Color%A_Index% = "") ? Col%A_Index% : Color%A_Index%
if instr(WindowStyles,"+altsubmit")
{
AltSub := "1" 
Stringreplace,WindowStyles,WindowStyles,`+altsubmit
}
Gui, Color, %Color1%,%Color1%
Gui, Font, s9
Gui, Font, %Font%, %Schriftart%
X := 20 ,Y := 20
ifexist, %IconPath%
{
Gui, Add, Picture, x20 y20 w32 h32, %IconPath%
X := 70 ,Y := 30
} else
if IconPath is integer
{
Gui, Add, Picture, x20 y20 icon%IconPath% w32 h32, %A_WinDir%\system32\shell32.dll
X := 70 ,Y := 30
}
Gui, Add, Text, x%X% y%Y% c%Color2% vStat2, %Text%
GuicontrolGet, Stat2, Pos
X2 = 10
Y2 := (Stat2Y + Stat2H < 52) ? 82 : Stat2Y + Stat2H + 30
HMax = 0
Gui, Add, Text, vStat1 +border -background
Loop, Parse, Buttons,|,`|
{
Gui, Add, Button, x%X2% w100 Y%Y2% gExButton , %A_Loopfield%
ButT%A_Index% := A_Loopfield
Guicontrolget, Button%A_Index%,Pos
if (HMax < Button%A_Index%H)
HMax := Button%A_Index%H
ABut := A_Index
X2 += 110
}
Loop %ABut%
Guicontrol, Move, Button%A_Index%,h%HMax%
Gui, %WindowStyles%
Gui, Show, Autosize Center,%Title%
Guicontrol, Move, Stat1, % "X-1 Y" Y2 - 10 " W" 1400 " h" 41 + HMax
Guicontrol, -Background +hidden, Stat1
Guicontrol, show, Stat1
Gui, +LastFound
WinGet, G_id
if Timeout !=
if Timeout is integer
settimer, Timeout, %Timeout%
Winwait, ahk_id %G_id%
retval = 0
while winexist("ahk_id " G_id)
sleep 100
if !AltSub
return ButT%retval%
else
return retval
Timeout:
if Timeout =
return
GuiClose:
Gui, destroy
return
ExButton:
MouseGetPos,,,, Control
Stringreplace,retval,Control,Button
Gui, destroy
return
}


;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Custom Msgbox
; Filename: cmsgbox.ahk
; Author  : Danny Ben Shitrit (aka Icarus)
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Copy this script or include it in your script (without the tester on top).
;
; Usage:
;   Answer := CMsgBox( title, text, buttons, icon="", owner=0 )
;   Where:
;     title   = The title of the message box.
;     text    = The text to display.
;     buttons = Pipe-separated list of buttons. Putting an asterisk in front of 
;               a button will make it the default.
;     icon    = If blank, we will use an info icon.
;               If a number, we will take this icon from Shell32.dll
;               If a letter ("I", "E" or "Q") we will use some predefined icons
;               from Shell32.dll (Info, Error or Question).
;     owner   = If 0, this will be a standalone dialog. If you want this dialog
;               to be owned by another GUI, place its number here.
;
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CMsgBox( title, text, buttons, icon="", owner=0 ) {
  Global _CMsg_Result

  GuiID := 9      ; If you change, also change the subroutines below

  StringSplit Button, buttons, |

  If( owner <> 0 ) {
    Gui %owner%:+Disabled
    Gui %GuiID%:+Owner%owner%
  }

  Gui %GuiID%:+Toolwindow +AlwaysOnTop

  MyIcon := ( icon = "I" ) or ( icon = "" ) ? 222 : icon = "Q" ? 24 : icon = "E" ? 110 : icon

  Gui %GuiID%:Add, Picture, Icon%MyIcon% , Shell32.dll
  Gui %GuiID%:Add, Text, x+12 yp w180 r8 section , %text%

  Loop %Button0% 
    Gui %GuiID%:Add, Button, % ( A_Index=1 ? "x+12 ys " : "xp y+3 " ) . ( InStr( Button%A_Index%, "*" ) ? "Default " : " " ) . "w100 gCMsgButton", % RegExReplace( Button%A_Index%, "\*" )

  Gui %GuiID%:Show,,%title%

  Loop 
    If( _CMsg_Result )
      Break

  If( owner <> 0 )
    Gui %owner%:-Disabled

  Gui %GuiID%:Destroy
  Result := _CMsg_Result
  _CMsg_Result := ""
  Return Result
}

9GuiEscape:
9GuiClose:
  _CMsg_Result := "Close"
Return

CMsgButton:
  StringReplace _CMsg_Result, A_GuiControl, &,, All
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

If/Else testing is confusing.  Try one of the following...

```
if (var="C")    ; case insensitive, use if (var=="C") for case sensitive
{
}
```

-or-

```
ifequal, var, C
{
}
```